# Why is "would" used in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, will-would

> I would roast you but my mom said I am not allowed to burn trash.

Why is "would" used in this sentence?

Answer (score 1):

> I would roast you but my mom said I am not allowed to burn trash.

Would is a past-tense form of will; however you can also use it to indicate something that was in the future at that point in time, but is not necessarily in the future right now. In your example, the person is saying that they *would* do something in the future *but* there is a reason that they will not.

You didn't ask about this, but for clarification, this statement is both a *put-down* (a criticism of someone else, often rude or offensive) and relies on a pun based around dual meanings of "roast". *To roast* something literally means to cook using heat, but a secondary meaning is to verbally tear someone down in a cruel, mocking way. So the person is actually indirectly calling the person "trash", and he *is* roasting him.

Comment: So is it like " I would roast you in normal conditions(because you did a roastable thing), but I will not roast you because my mother said I am not allowed to burn trash.?

Comment: @lollel123 Exactly - but its all a pun, because the advice from his mother, if it is even real, is about *literally burning* trash; and by saying all of this, he *is* roasting him

Comment: Well explained and it's actually pretty funny.

Comment: @Astralbee Can you explain more? Why is the first clause used in the sentence?

Comment: @lollel123 I *would* explain it again *but* I covered it in my answer. When we "I would have... but", we are giving a reason why we *are not going to do* something. The person is saying they *would* have roasted the person, but there is a reason they didn't. I appreciate that this is a complex example, because the sentence is not *sincere*. The whole statement *is* a roast.

Comment: Why do the speaker have to say "I would roast you"?, what if I omit the first clause?

Comment: By saying I would roast you, is the speaker saying that his  or her mom is the only reason I am not going to roast you, and It is not like I can't roast you or anything" ?

Comment: @lollel123 It is quite clear when you understand the dual meaning of "roast" (and also of "burn") that the mom's advice has nothing at all to do with the matter at hand. Maybe the mom didn't even give this advice. The entire statement is an insult, calling the other person "trash". It's similar to another insult "*I can't take the piss out of you, because you can't take the piss out of shit*".

Comment: I know , I completely understood the meaning of the sentence. I am only confused by WOULD.

Answer (score 0):

Even though 'would' is the past tense of 'will', [we use would and could for hypothetical situations in the future](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/will-and-would). In this case, the scenario with which we're presented is hypothetical. The hypothesis being "If you weren't trash, I could burn you because I wouldn't be going against mum's rule of not burning trash".

The same rule applies if we consider the initial statement a conditional since [we use 'would' as a helping verb to show that something might be likely or meant to happen under certain conditions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would). The condition being mom's rule once again.